# ES6: Filter array in chunks to not freeze the UI

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I'am trying to filter a huge array. Unfortunately the array is so big that the UI freezes. That's why I'm trying to perform the filtering in chunks with a timeout in between, so that the UI can load.

For demonstration purposes I take the "huge" array `[1,2,3,4,5]` and return the elements which are dividable by two.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].filter(async (x) => {
    // wait 1 sec after each element to filter
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    return x % 2 === 0;
});
```

Any ideas how to filter a big array so that the UI doesn't freeze?

Comment: You should look into [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: Try passing your array to outer JSON API service that will filter the array for you ;)

Comment: Maybe try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/mb8qnt1L/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` cannot work with `async` predicate because predicate must return boolean value, but an `async` predicate will return a promise.

you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to chain your async calls and construct filter result by yourself.

```
async function filterAsync(array, predicate) {
    const res = [];

    await array.reduce(async (promise, n) => {
        await promise;
        if (await predicate(n)) {
            res.push(n);
        }
    }, Promise.resolve());

    return res;
}


filterAsync([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], async x => {
    // wait 1 sec after each element to filter
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    return x % 2 === 0;
}).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill an empty array with the filtered element in an async manner, the caveat is the order may not be the same as the original array:

```
var ret = []
var promiseArray = [1,2,3,4,5].map( async x => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(resolve, 1000)})
    if (x % 2 === 0) {
        ret.push(x)
    }
})
Promise.all(promiseArray).then(()=> {console.log(ret)})
```